# Using Beacon Library from background service

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am trying to use Android Beacon Library in an app that runs as a background service. I bind beaconManager on my service starting. I unbind onDestroy. I then want to stop and start the ranging based on user action (on_duty / off_duty)

I have tried several combinations over last week but I can't seem to get it just right where the ranging will always restart properly after I have stopped it. In some cases I get the following from BeaconIntentProcessor:

```
"but ranging notifier is null, so we're dropping it."
```

What are the right methods to call both to stop and start ranging?
Should I not be able to bind and unbind service based on (on_duty / off_duty)
(I have tried this but have not been able to make it work consistently)

My app is for personal in field using beacons to do periodic checkins at different locations while on_duty and would like to disable BLE in app while off_duty to conserve battery. While app is in off_duty mode my app still maintains background service for other functionality.

Below is the startup sequence. Not sure if there is a problem - at the end it keeps looping through the same "Restarting scan" sequence.

```
10-06 23:23:16.348: D/BeaconService(9203): No org.altbeacon.beacon.SimulatedScanData class exists.
10-06 23:23:16.348: I/BeaconService(9203): binding
10-06 23:23:16.408: I/BeaconService(9203): start monitoring received
10-06 23:23:16.408: D/BeaconService(9203): startMonitoring called
10-06 23:23:16.408: D/BeaconService(9203): Currently monitoring 1 regions.
10-06 23:23:16.408: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): startLeScan(): null
10-06 23:23:16.468: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
10-06 23:23:16.468: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 1100 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:16.468: D/BeaconService(9203): Scan started
10-06 23:23:17.478: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 99 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:17.568: D/BeaconService(9203): Done with scan cycle
10-06 23:23:17.598: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): stopLeScan()

10-06 23:23:17.608: D/BeaconService(9203): Restarting scan.  Unique beacons seen last cycle: 0 Total beacon advertisement packets seen: 0
10-06 23:23:17.608: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): startLeScan(): null
10-06 23:23:17.618: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
10-06 23:23:17.618: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 5000 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:17.618: D/BeaconService(9203): Scan started
10-06 23:23:18.618: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 3999 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:18.978: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onScanResult() - Device=78:A5:04:5B:1A:F9 RSSI=-48
10-06 23:23:18.978: D/BeaconService(9203): got record
10-06 23:23:19.618: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 2998 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:19.878: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onScanResult() - Device=78:A5:04:5B:1A:F9 RSSI=-48
10-06 23:23:19.878: D/BeaconService(9203): got record
10-06 23:23:20.618: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 1998 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:20.788: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onScanResult() - Device=78:A5:04:5B:1A:F9 RSSI=-48
10-06 23:23:20.788: D/BeaconService(9203): got record
10-06 23:23:21.618: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 997 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:21.698: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onScanResult() - Device=78:A5:04:5B:1A:F9 RSSI=-48
10-06 23:23:21.698: D/BeaconService(9203): got record
10-06 23:23:22.608: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onScanResult() - Device=78:A5:04:5B:1A:F9 RSSI=-48
10-06 23:23:22.608: D/BeaconService(9203): got record
10-06 23:23:22.618: D/BeaconService(9203): Done with scan cycle
10-06 23:23:22.618: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): stopLeScan()

10-06 23:23:22.628: D/BeaconService(9203): Restarting scan.  Unique beacons seen last cycle: 0 Total beacon advertisement packets seen: 0
10-06 23:23:22.638: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): startLeScan(): null
10-06 23:23:22.638: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
10-06 23:23:22.648: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 5000 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:22.648: D/BeaconService(9203): Scan started
10-06 23:23:23.658: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 3993 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:24.418: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onScanResult() - Device=78:A5:04:5B:1A:F9 RSSI=-46
10-06 23:23:24.418: D/BeaconService(9203): got record
10-06 23:23:24.658: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 2993 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:25.328: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onScanResult() - Device=78:A5:04:5B:1A:F9 RSSI=-47
10-06 23:23:25.328: D/BeaconService(9203): got record
10-06 23:23:25.658: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 1992 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:26.228: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onScanResult() - Device=78:A5:04:5B:1A:F9 RSSI=-46
10-06 23:23:26.228: D/BeaconService(9203): got record
10-06 23:23:26.658: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 991 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:27.648: D/BeaconService(9203): Done with scan cycle
10-06 23:23:27.648: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): stopLeScan()
10-06 23:23:27.658: D/BeaconService(9203): Restarting scan.  Unique beacons seen last cycle: 0 Total beacon advertisement packets seen: 0
10-06 23:23:27.658: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): startLeScan(): null
10-06 23:23:27.668: D/BluetoothAdapter(9203): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
10-06 23:23:27.678: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 5000 milliseconds
10-06 23:23:27.678: D/BeaconService(9203): Scan started
10-06 23:23:28.678: D/BeaconService(9203): Waiting to stop scan for another 3999 milliseconds
```

------------- SimpleService Code below -------------

```
public class SimpleService extends Service implements BeaconConsumer
{
protected static final String TAG = "MyBeaconService";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
RangingData rangingData = null;
Beacon beacon = null;
int  mapKey = 0;

ArrayList<String> sBeacons = new ArrayList<String>();
Hashtable<Integer, String> source = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();

final HashMap<Integer, String>  map = new HashMap(source);
final HashMap<Integer, String>  maptime = new HashMap(source);

String[] parts = null;


public class SimpleServiceBinder extends Binder
{
    public SimpleService getService()
    {

        return SimpleService.this;
    }
}




@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service created ...");

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getBaseContext());

 //   beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make  it
    // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
    // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
    // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb
    //
    // beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
    //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=aabb,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));


    beaconManager.bind(this);


    beaconManager.debug = true;
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(1000);


}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    Log.i(TAG,"onStart called");

    beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.i(TAG,"onStartCommand called");

    return START_STICKY; //START_REDELIVER_INTENT; 
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service destroyed ...");
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     beaconManager.unbind(this);
}


    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "<<< onBeaconServiceConnect  >>>");

        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() 
        {


        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region)
        {

          Log.i(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect \ngetId1: "+region.getId1()+"\ngetId2: "+region.getId2()+"\ngetId3: "+region.getId3());
          Log.i(TAG, "**************-------------****************");


          logBeaconData(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) 
        {
            //logToDisplay("Exit Region "+ region.getUniqueId(), true);
             Log.i(TAG, "********!!!!!!!!! didExitRegion !!!!!!!!!!*******");
             mapKey = 0;
             logBeaconData(false);
             try 
             {
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("sBeacon", null, null, null));
             } catch (RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace();}

             Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = map.keySet().iterator();

            while(keySetIterator.hasNext())
            {   
                Integer key = keySetIterator.next();

                Log.i(TAG, "****DELETE key: " + mapKey + " value: " + map.get(key));
                keySetIterator.remove();
                maptime.remove(key);

            }
            printtoscreen();


        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) 
        {

             Log.i(TAG, "didDetermineStateForRegion \ngetId1: "+region.getId1()+"\ngetId2: "+region.getId2()+"\ngetId3: "+region.getId3());
        }


        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("sBeacon", null, null, null));

        } catch (RemoteException e) {  Log.i(TAG, "RemoteException: "+e);   }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param iBeacon
     */
    private void logBeaconData(final boolean enter)
    {
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() 
        {
        @Override 
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) 
        {

            if (beacons.size() > 0) 
            {

            //  sBeacons.clear();

                beacon = beacons.iterator().next();

                Log.i(TAG, " UUID: " + beacon.getId1());
                Log.i(TAG, " Major: " + beacon.getId2());
                Log.i(TAG, " Minor: " + beacon.getId3());
                Log.i(TAG, " RSSI: " + beacon.getRssi());
                Log.i(TAG, " Power: "+ beacon.getTxPower());
                Log.i(TAG, " Distance: "+ beacon.getDistance());



                    if (map.values().contains(beacon.getIdentifiers().toString()))
                    {
                   //   Log.i(TAG, "<<< Already there >>> "+beacon.getIdentifiers().toString());

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mapKey = mapKey + 1;
                        map.put(mapKey, beacon.getIdentifiers().toString());
                        maptime.put(mapKey, ""+System.currentTimeMillis());

                    }

                    Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = map.keySet().iterator();

                    final int seconds = 10;

                    while(keySetIterator.hasNext())
                    {   
                        Integer key = keySetIterator.next();


                        if (map.get(key).contains(beacon.getIdentifiers().toString()))
                        {
                            maptime.put(key, ""+System.currentTimeMillis());    
                        }

                        long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - (Long.parseLong(maptime.get(key)));

                        int second = (int) ((diff / 1000) % 60);
                        Log.i(TAG, "key: " + key + " value: " + map.get(key)+" diff: "+second);

                        if(second >= seconds )
                        {
                            Log.i(TAG, "****DELETE key: " + mapKey + " value: " + map.get(key)+" diff: "+second);
                            keySetIterator.remove();    
                            maptime.remove(key);
                            //logToDisplay("\n** Beacon not longer reporting **"+ map.get(key), true); 
                        }
                        printtoscreen();

                    }

            }

        }

        });

        try
        {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("sBeacon", null, null, null));
            Log.i(TAG, "*** startRangingBeaconsInRegion ***");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {  Log.i(TAG, "RemoteException: "+e);   }

    }
    public void printtoscreen()
    {
        Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
         //   logToDisplay("", false);
            while(keySetIterator.hasNext())
            {   
                Integer key = keySetIterator.next();

                Log.i(TAG, "---------------------------------------------------");
                if (map.get(key) != null)
                {
                     parts = map.get(key).toString().substring(1, map.get(key).toString().length()-1).split("\\,");

                    Log.i(TAG, "---------------------------------------------------");
                    Log.i(TAG, "UUID:  " + parts[0]);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Major: " + parts[1]);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Minor: " + parts[2]);
                    Log.i(TAG, "RSSI: "+ beacon.getRssi());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Power: "+ beacon.getTxPower());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Distance: "+ beacon.getDistance());
                }


            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please write questions for the community; and not individuals and authors.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem doing what you want if you set it up properly.

I suspect you get the "ranging notifier is null" because you did not set the ranging notifier in the onBeaconServiceConnect() callback.  If you do set the ranging notifier in this method, you probably need to post your code so we can assist further.

Comment: I do have the ranging notifier set in onBeaconServiceConnect() callback. I think I am loosing it when I restart my service. Or I if I set it a second time it get's messed up. My code usually works on initial start. Is is when I restart it stops working. Should I always unbind beacon service and then bind on restart? I have tried this approach and then get what I posted above to my original post.

Comment: Can you please post your code?  Otherwise we're just taking stabs in the dark.

Comment: @ davidgyoung: i am getting the same. I have used this code. http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html

Comment: @davidgyoung I have updated my original post to include the SimpleService code above.